# Why is PHP still displaying errors?

Tags: apache, php-5.3, redhat

Recently upgrading to PHP 5.3 has resulted in a slew of depreciation errors being shown on my pages. In php.ini I have display_errors off and error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED, but the errors still show. Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the ini has been loaded after the edit? Maybe apache configuration overrides php flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script could be setting the error reporting level differently. Preferably at the end of the page that's having problems run:

```
phpinfo();
```

It will give you the global, and local values for display_errors. It's likely been turned on at some point.

If you establish that it's being turned back on, you'll need to find where it's turned back on, and remove that. Searching for ini_set() within your project will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply this sort of change, you have to reload apache.

Answer (score 0):

restart PHP and execute script like this:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

to confirm changes