# PHP does not show any errors

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

I have this code which should of course throw a few errors. But no errors are displayed at all, it just loads a blank page. I read [PHP not displaying errors even though display_errors = On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480425/php-not-displaying-errors-even-though-display-errors-on) but it did not help.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    blaswagagsd
    gfdasgyoloeaifs

    echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] sdfga
?>
```

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
display_errors = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

error_reporting = E_ALL
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I also set the same settings in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. Of course I restarted Apache after I changed the `php.ini`.
What else can I try?

Comment: check `phpinfo()` and make sure those are the proper .ini files. and check for php_value directives in .htaccess files, other apache .conf files, which can override the .ini settings.

Comment: There are multiple `.htaccess` files, how can i find out which is the right one? It found: `./usr/share/doc/debian-reference-common/html/.htaccess`
`./usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib/.htaccess`
`./usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/.htaccess`
`./usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/.htaccess`

Comment: you have to check every single one that could affect the script. e.g. look in the script's directory, and ever parent directory upwards.

Comment: create your .htaccess file in your project.

Comment: I created an empty `.htaccess` file in my project folder. Still no errors are getting displayed. What do i have to enter in this ".htaccess" file?

Comment: you tried to ini_set with a string?
ini_set('display_errors', "1");

Comment: @Paladin76 [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) states _Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed._ (which is fairly obvious), so the in-script settings wont apply here anyways. And nope, the numeric 1 is correct here.

Comment: i know what is written, i just asked if he tried? i have had some servers when this was important to work! you never know...

Comment: ye ye i try as you can see in my given code.

Comment: also, check your "error_log" and "log_errors" in your php.ini

Comment: The .htaccess in your files' directory should contain two lines: `php_value display_errors = On` and `php_value error_reporting = E_ALL`. Could you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was that there is another "display_errors" somewhere on the bottom of the `php.ini`, which set `display_errors = Off`, so changing the first occurence of "display_errors" CAN'T work. Either set this `display_errors` to `On` or delete the line.
I am wondering why the original creators of `php.ini` set this trap.